# WCF - question about endpoint element under system.serviceModel in config file

Tags: wcf, wcf-configuration

While implementing a WCF client endpoint, my config file had the following endpoint entry:

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost/MyProject/Services/MyService.svc/MyService"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" 
      contract="MyNamespace.IContract" />
```

At this point the service is NOT hosted in IIS. Essentially, I am using Cassini to call through to the app. This configuration works fine. However, if I remove the /Myservice element and my config looks like this:

```
    <endpoint address="http://localhost/MyProject/Services/MyService.svc"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" 
      contract="MyNamespace.IContract" />
```

I get the following exception:

> System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: Content Type text/xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched

Why does the second config breaks while the first one works? What's so special about the /MyService part of the url?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it's a problem with the way you defined the endpoint on the service side. Try this:

```
  <service
    name="NameOfYourService">

    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost/MyProject/Services/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>

    <endpoint
      address=""
      binding="basicHttpBinding"
      contract="Namespace.Contract" />

  </service>
```